# loop through multiple collections in java code

Tags: java, collections, for-loop

I have 4 collections each containing time saved at specific moments of time. I would say that my my question is rather general so what the collections contain is not important. I was wondering how I could possibly loop through these collections at the same time, get the size and return the longest collection. Does this make sense?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried yet

Comment: No it doesn't make sense. Can you give sample inputs, expected outputs, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: It would be a good idea to refer to Java documentation of the classes you use ..

Comment: what do you mean by "at the same time"? literally or just take a few collections and compare their contents at a certain point in time?

Comment: Can you provide an example to explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Why should you iterate over a Collection to know its size? Collection has `size()` method

Comment: he is saying `at the same time` something... `4 collections`...

Comment: maybe he wants to iterate over a collection of collections ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have collections that implement the interface Collection, you can just use

```
Collection.size();
```

to provide the length of the collection.

Then you can compare the results of the size() calls to find the longest collection.

You don't have to iterate over all the items in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways:

- You could union your collections into one by using [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) from Apache Commons for instance
- You could put your collections into another collection/list. Collection is implementing Iterator so you could simply iterate through them.
- You could recursively call a method given the collection.

I think you should go with the second approach and store the size in a variable and replace it if the new collection is bigger.

```
int size = -1;
for (Collection col : allCollections) {
    if (col.size() > size) size = col.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example-

```
List<Integer> l1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> l2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> l3=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> l4=new ArrayList<Integer>();

l1.add(1);l1.add(1);
l2.add(2);l2.add(2);l2.add(2);
l3.add(3);l3.add(3);l3.add(3);l3.add(3);
l4.add(4);l4.add(4);l4.add(4);

System.out.println("L1 size "+l1.size());
System.out.println("L2 size "+l2.size());
System.out.println("L3 size "+l3.size());
System.out.println("L4 size "+l4.size());
String array="l1";
int i=l1.size();
if(i<l2.size())
    array="l2";
if(i<l3.size())
    array="l3";
if(i<l4.size())
    array="l4"; 
System.out.println("Largest Array is = "+array);
```

Here is the output

```
L1 size 2
L2 size 3
L3 size 4
L4 size 3
Largest Array is = l4
```

Is that what u want?